# How do I query features above a certain height in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I'd like to query all objects that are taller than 20m within a bounding box on OSM?

Is this possible so I can place them on a map or even generate a map tile with them drawn on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [query Overpass API](http://overpass-turbo.eu/?template=key&key=height) for all objects that do have a [`height`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:height) tag in the first place and then filter the results yourself in any language that can process JSON or XML (Overpass cannot compare tag values with `>`).

Comment: There is already a feature request for supporting greater than, less than etc. at [issue 78](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/78).

Comment: This is not surprising at all!